# What is a "pedagogical reflection" in a teaching statement?

Tags: teaching, job, teaching-statement

I am in the process of applying for an academic position in Europe. They have asked for a short pedagogical reflection in teaching statement, but I do not understand that. In the college that I am working now they have designed an online questionnaire to get students' feedback. The report is not available for public and it is in fact an internal report. Can I just copy that tables including the results? If so, how can the hiring committee validate that reports and results? Or they just rely on what I have written?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would guess that they are asking more about your teaching philosophy than about feedback per se. Stating that you get good student feedback is fine, but I'd think they want more.

How do you interact with students? What sorts of exercises do you use? What is your grading philosophy (perhaps)? What do you expect outside of class? How do you manage questions in lecture? What sorts of materials do you provide?

But the above are just elements of a general teaching philosophy. For some universities teaching is a much more important element of the job than in others. Perhaps that is the case here.

Comment: Good answer, only want to add: there are lots of resources for writing teaching statements. Here's [one](https://cft.vanderbilt.edu/guides-sub-pages/teaching-statements/).

Comment: Think about how you teach. Are the classes you run _Socratic_ (you ask questions, trying to force the answers to the points you want to make)? Do you pick up a piece of chaulk when you walk in the door, and then write on the board for 55 minutes? Can every test question be found in a chapter you assigned for reading (or in the stuff you wrote on the board)? Do you value "the points I made in class" or a more general understanding of the subject? Do you believe in closed or open book tests? Caveat: I'm not a teacher

Answer (score 6):

Pedagogical reflection means to critically review your teaching methods in order to improve upon them. What worked? What didn't? How can you improve?

Here's [link](https://jethe.org/index.php/jethe/article/view/213/47) to a recent paper from the Journal of Effective Teaching in Higher Education (vol. 4(1)) by Emily E. Virtue, "Pedagogical Reflection: Demonstrating the Value of Introspection."

DOI: https://doi.org/10.36021/jethe.v4i1.213

Note: This was found via a Google search using the phrase 'pedagogical reflection'